# PySide timers/threading crash

Tags: multithreading, pyqt, pyside

I've written a PySide Windows application that uses libvlc to show a video, log keystrokes, and write aggregated information about those keystrokes to a file. I'm experiencing two bugs that are causing the application to crash (other question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326943/pyside-qlistwidget-crash).

The application writes the keystroke file at every five minute interval on the video. Users can change the playback speed, so that five minute interval may take more or less than five minutes; it's not controlled by a timer.

The video continues playing while the file is written, so I've created an object inheriting from threading.Thread for the file creation - IntervalFile. Some information about the file to be written is passed in the constructor; IntervalFile doesn't access its parent (the main QWidget) at all. This is the only threading object I use in the app. There are no timer declared anywhere.

Intermittently, the application will crash and I'll get the following message: "**QObject::killTimers: timers cannot be stopped from another thread**".

The code that creates IntervalFile is (part of CustomWidget, inherited from QWidget):

```
def doIntervalChange(self):
  ...
  ifile = IntervalFile(5, filepath, dbpath) # db is sqlite, with new connection created within IntervalFile
  ifile.start()
  #end of def
```

doIntervalChange is called from within QWidget using a signal.
IntervalFile is:

```
class IntervalFile(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, interval, filepath, dbpath):
    # declaration of variables

    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    shutil.copy('db.local', self.dbPath) # because db is still being used in main QWidget
    self.localDB = local(self.dbPath) # creates connection to sqlite db, with sql within the object to make db calls easier

    # query db for keystroke data
    # write file

    self.localDB.close()
    self.localDB = None

    os.remove(self.dbPath) # don't need this copy anymore
```

When ifile.start() is commented out, I don't see the killTimers crash. Any suggestions? Note that the crash seems random; sometimes I can use the app (just continuely pressing the same keystroke over and over) for an hour without it crashing, sometimes it's within the first couple of intervals. Because of this difficulty reproducing the crashes, I think these lines of code are the issue, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to hold a reference to your thread object. When your `doIntervalChange()` method finishes, nothing is holding a reference to the thread object (ifile) any more and so it can be garbage collected. Presumably this is why the crash happens randomly (if the thread finishes it's task before the object is garbage collected, then you don't have a problem).

Not exactly sure what is creating the QTimers, but I'm fairly certain that won't affect my proposed solution!

So in doIntervalChange() save a reference to ifile in a list, and periodically clean up the list when threads have finished execution. Have a look at this for an idea (and if a better way to clean up threads shows up in that post, implement that!): [Is there a more elegant way to clean up thread references in python? Do I even have to worry about them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347689/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-clean-up-thread-references-in-python-do-i-even-h)

Comment: The code I posted was simplified; I had actually already tried this before posting the question. Thanks for the try though

Comment: Ah. Well worth a shot! Any chance you can post a minmilistic example that displays the problem?

Comment: The project was due quite some time ago, and I ended up re-writing the entire app in a language I was more familiar with. It's relatively complex and rendering it down to just a simple example would be time-consuming and isn't something I have incentive for right now. Thanks for trying to help out though, this was extremely frustrating for me.