# Is there a more elegant way to clean up thread references in python? Do I even have to worry about them?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I am working with QThreads from pyqt4. I have a thread that is always running, let's call it main. In the constructor, main initializes an empty list. I spawn child threads from main by appending them to the list:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def spawn(self):
    download_t = DownloadWorker() #this subclasses QtCore.QThread
    download_t.talker.connect(self.exec_js)
    download_t.start()
    self.items.append(download_t)
```

If I don't store a reference in this list, the thread dies as soon as execution leaves spawn().

I have another method in main that is triggered by an event each second:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def cleanup(self):
    for t in self.items:
        if t.isFinished():
            self.items.remove(t)
```

This removes the child threads when they are finished. My question is:

1. **Do I even need to do this?** Will python gc these references for me?
2. **Is there a better way** to cleanup the references without looping over the entire list of threads every second? One way I have considered is storing the threads in a dict where the key is Thread-n. The child threads themselves would trigger cleanup with an event.

**EDIT**: So what I ended up doing was using QThreadPool to manage my threads instead of reinventing the wheel, so now I have something that looks like:

```
...
self.pool = QTCore.QThreadPool()
...
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
def spawn(self):
    download_t = DownloadWorker() #this subclasses QtCore.QRunnable
    download_t.talker.result.connect(self.exec_js) #result is a QObject to handle
                                                   #signals
    self.pool.start(download_t)
```

No more need to poll for cleanup!